# Why the childFragmentManager.popBackStack() not working in Fragment for Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I want to close the fragment inside fragment. I use the following code to add the `Fragment` from the `Activity`.

**`Activity -> Fragment-A -> Fragment-B`**

In **`Activity`**:

```
addFragment(AFragment(),R.id.fragment_layout,FragTag.fragA)

fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int, tag:String){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,0,0,R.anim.slide_out_right)
            add(frameId, fragment)
            addToBackStack(tag)
        }.commit()
}
```

In **`Fragment-A`**,for create **`fragment-B`**

```
addFragment(TestBFragment(),R.id.childFragment_layout,FragTag.fragB)

    private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int, tag:String) {
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,0,0,R.anim.slide_out_right)
            add(frameId, fragment)
            addToBackStack(tag)
        }.commit()
    }
```

The above code work fine, but it is not working to use the following code to close fragment-B by itself.

```
childFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
childFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

And the `childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount` return 0 in `fragment-B`

Did I missing something ?

How to close `fragment` by itself via `childFragmentManager` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `childFragmentManager` of fragment *A* is identical to the `fragmentManager` of fragment *B*. So to remove *B* from within *A*, you have to call

```
childFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

To remove *B* from within *B* itself, you have to call

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

The `childFragmentManager` of fragment *B* was never used to add another fragment and thus the backstack is empty.

Comment: 'getter for fragmentManager: FragmentManager?' is deprecated.
Use `parentFragmentManager` instead of `FragmentManager`